# Let $A$ be an event and $Y$ real

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $A$ be an event and $Y$ real random variable. Prove that function $\alpha$ is the conditional probability of the event $A$ with respect to $Y$ exactly when each $y \in R$ apply $$P(A\cap {Y≤y}) = E[\alpha(Y)1(Y≤y)]$$

Comment: "I really do not know how to start." From the definition of the conditional expectation/probability, obviously. What is it already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition, $\mathbb{P}(A|Y) = \mathbb{E}[1(A)|Y]$. So $\alpha(Y) = \mathbb{P}(A|Y)$ if and only if $\alpha(Y)$ satisfy the definition of the conditional expectation. Now the question given that for all $y \in \mathbb{R}$,
$$ \mathbb{P}(A \cap Y \leq y) = \mathbb{E}[1(A)1(Y\leq y)] = \mathbb{E}[\alpha(Y)1(Y\leq y)]$$
The latter equality is the definition of conditional expectation $\alpha(Y) = \mathbb{E}[1(A)|Y]$, as every Borel set can be constructed by the intersection/union of the intervals in the form of $(-\infty, y]$.